# Disable Google Chrome Caching for Development

Tags: google-chrome, caching

It's absolutely impossible for me to use Chrome for developing, because it caches javascript and css files. Even when using development mode, hell - even when I do the 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' - it's still caching and does not reload!

Is there anything I can do to prevent Chrome from caching while using the 'inspect mode'?

Comment: There's an option in the DevTools settings to disable the cache. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

To disable the Chrome cache for development do the following:

1. Open the dev tools (Ctrl + Shift + J)
2. Click on the ... menu in the Dev tools and pick Settings
3. Scroll down to"Network" and you will see the option to disable the cache

[image]

Comment: Notice that the option is enabled "while DevTools is open."  I find that it works under this condition (only).  What I do is click-and-drag the topof the DevTools pane to the bottom of my Chrome window to leave the cache disabled when I don't want DevTools obstructing the main browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I use this add-on: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en

It works great.